# i am receiving Error 'groups' using Foursquare

Tags: python-requests, foursquare

*Hi there
i have reset my credentials as suggested in similar question previously, however i am
still receiving the same error 'groups'.....*

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes):
radius=500
LIMIT=100
venues_list=[]
for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
    print(name)
        
    
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v= 
    {}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
        CLIENT_ID, 
        CLIENT_SECRET, 
        VERSION, 
        lat, 
        lng, 
        radius, 
        LIMIT)
        
    
    results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
    
    
    venues_list.append([(
        name, 
        lat, 
        lng, 
        v['venue']['name'], 
        v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
        v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
        v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 
              'Neighborhood Latitude', 
              'Neighborhood Longitude', 
              'Venue', 
              'Venue Latitude', 
              'Venue Longitude', 
              'Venue Category']

return(nearby_venues)

illembe_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df_illembe['Neighborhood'],
                               latitudes=df_illembe['Latitude'],
                               longitudes=df_illembe['Longitude']
                              )
```

*i have also written the code in a new notebook and receiving the same error*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am recieiving the key error "groups', as per below, with the above code.